# Should there be any follow up actions for unaccepted answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I have noticed that there are quite a few questions with an unaccepted answer. Should we follow up with any actions for these types of posts?

I see two categories of unaccepted answers:

1. User asks question, another user answers the question

> Examples:
>
> - [How to return error from chain extension?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/how-to-return-error-from-chain-extension)
> - [Once the referendum is over, can the democratic proposals passed be implemented directly?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/once-the-referendum-is-over-can-the-democratic-proposals-passed-be-implemented)
> - [How do I upgrade my node's RPC?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/how-do-i-upgrade-my-nodes-rpc)

2. User asks question, same user answers their own question

> Examples:
>
> - [Why does my unit test pass when verifying signed metadata, but fails when signing through Polkadot.js](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/why-does-my-unit-test-pass-when-verifying-signed-metadata-but-fails-when-signin)
> - [Storage Migration Guide Using #[pallet::storage]](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/storage-migration-guide-using-palletstorage)

Also important to mention that if you answer your own question you have to wait 2 days before you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mighty [docs](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final
> statement indicating that the question has now been answered
> perfectly. **It simply means that the author received an answer that
> worked for them personally.** Not every user comes back to accept an
> answer, and of those who do, they might not change the accepted answer
> even if a newer, better answer comes along later.
>
> Often, accepting an answer corresponds to reputation gains.
>
> If you accept:
>
> **someone else's answer**: You gain +2 reputation and the author of the
> accepted answer earns +15 reputation.
>
> **your own answer**: No reputation
> is awarded, and the answer does not float to the top of the list. You
> must wait 48 hours to accept your own answer.

Based on this, I do not see much of a priority in *nudging* users to accept an answer, although from a psychological perspective, IMO, I feel more confident when I see an accepted answer vs an unaccepted answer, especially if I am a newcomer to a topic.